# Get elements in nested array

Tags: numpy

I have a `np.array= [[1,2,3,4],[2,1,4,1],[0,9,2,1],...]`
Can I somehow without loops get every second element in each nested array, I want to get `[[2],[1],[9]]`
Or this can be done only with loops?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 2nd element of every row

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,1,4,1],[0,9,2,1]]) 
arr[:, 1]
```